# What is the meaning of 'Past the point'?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I'm not a native english speaker and I'm still learning english, I've heard this word from the movie I've watched recently its called 13 reasons why and the sentence goes like 'And I'm glad I was past the point that my dad could scare the sh!t out of me'  Could anyone please help.

Answer (score 2):

To be **past the point where** is to have gone beyond.

It can be used literally:

> We are past the point where we can get gas. The last filling station
>   for 100 miles was several miles back.

or figuratively:

> He was past the point where he was afraid of that bully.

He had reached a mental or emotional stage where he no longer feared the bully.

Comment: Can I have more examples, like Past the point when or anything that I can use with this phrase.

Comment: @Rick8589 `I was past the point when I could do anything about it`, the point in this case is a point in time. The phrase is used both with physical distances and points in time, so you can use it whenever you have passed a specific physical point or a specific time.